# MySQL query which has multiple subqueries, each with different join types

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

Let me start by giving you a diagram of the relationships between the tables used in my mysql query:

[image: table relationship]
<sub>(source: [r717.net](http://eintranet.r717.net/index_htm_files/perm_relationships.png))</sub>

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `permissions`
WHERE   `id` IN (
    SELECT      pr.perm_id 
    FROM        `user_roles` as ur 
    LEFT JOIN   `permissions_role` as pr 
    ON          ur.role_id = pr.role_id
    WHERE       ur.user_id = '$userid'
)
OR      `id` IN (
    SELECT      `perm_id` 
    FROM        `permissions_user` 
    WHERE       `user_id` = '$userid'
)
```

`$userid` is the id from the user table for the current user. I store the permission name from the result into an array which represents all permissions assigned to the user based on his/her role **and** his/her id:

```
<?php
$user_perms = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0):
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query):
        $user_perms[] = $result('name');
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

`print_r($user_perms);` produces an output that looks like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => ACCESS_TELEPHONELIST_PAGE
    [1] => ACCESS_VACATIONSCHED_PAGE
    [2] => ACCESS_TOURSCHED_PAGE
    [3] => ACCESS_WORKSCHED_PAGE
    [4] => ACCESS_RESOURCES_LINKS
    [5] => ACCESS_PMTOOL_PAGE
    [6] => ACCESS_TOOLSTOOL_PAGE
    [7] => ACCESS_SHOPTOOLLIST_PAGE
    [8] => ACCESS_TOOLINVENTORY_PAGE
    [9] => ACCESS_MANAGETOOLLIST_PAGE
    [10] => ACCESS_TOOLREPORTS_PAGE
    [11] => ACCESS_JOBSLIST_LINKS
    [12] => MAIN_TAB_TOOLSTOOL
    [13] => ADMIN_TAB_PODMANAGEMENT
    [14] => TOOL_TAB_SHOPTOOLLIST
)
```

What I want to do is to **also** store all of the user's roles into another array without making a second query. I thought I needed to use aliases for the sub queries, so I tried this query:

```
SELECT      permissions.*, usersroles.role_id 
FROM        `permissions`
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT      ur.user_id, pr.perm_id, ur.role_id
    FROM        `user_roles` as ur
    LEFT JOIN   `permissions_role` as pr 
    ON          ur.role_id = pr.role_id
    WHERE       ur.user_id = '$userid'
) AS usersroles ON usersroles.perm_id = permissions.id
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT      `perm_id`, `user_id` 
    FROM        `permissions_user` 
    WHERE       `user_id` = '$userid'
) AS userperms ON userperms.user_id = usersroles.user_id
              AND userperms.perm_id = permissions.id
```

and, using code similar to the code above...

```
<?php
$user_perms = array();
$user_roles = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0):
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query):
        $user_perms = $result('name');
        $user_roles = $result('role_id');
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

... I get this warning:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

But, I would like to `print_r($user_roles);` and produce an output that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => administrator
    [1] => humanresources
    [2] => podmanager
)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or suggest a better way to get the data I need from **one** query into **2** arrays?

**EDIT :** After careful consideration, I changed my code to use 2 queries as ImreL suggested. The resulting code works nicely and executes quickly. I have edited my answer to show the final code I used and added supporting code to demonstrate how I am using the 2 queries. Big thanks to ImreL!

Comment: Nice diagram :) What tool did you use to create it?

Comment: I used Microsoft Access... created the tables, and setup the relationships, then went to design view and took a screenshot with my graphics program.

Comment: There's probably an error in your SQL syntax. Try adding `or die(mysql_error());` after the `mysql_query` call, e.g. `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());` as a quick way to see what's wrong with your query. I can't immediately spot any problems, but it's getting late over here :) As an aside, why can't you use two queries? If I'm understanding correctly, it seems you're after two completely different things here, because not all permissions are associated with role IDs, so you're going to have some NULLs in there no matter what.

Comment: Well, all roles do have permissions, and all users have one or more roles, but some users have permissions that their roles do not have. The query will be required to run on every page the user loads and we have over 30,000 permissions, and 3,000 roles. I am just trying **very hard** to keep my number of queries to a minimum. We also host our 7 sites on a server in our office, and the server doesn't seem to be capable of handling the amount of traffic we generate (unfortunately I have no control over this) :-)

Comment: @AmyMcCrobie: To be clear, you are trying to obtain two entirely separate and unconnected arrays - one of every permission the current user has (whether granted to them or to one of their roles) and, separately, one of every role they have?  You're not looking to understand which permission came from where?  Is that correct?

Comment: @eggyal: yes, that is correct. @Daan: Thank you! I added the `or die(mysql_error());` after the `mysql_query` call. Doing so helped me to more quickly see what was wrong with the many other queries I tried. Ultimately, there was not an error in the query syntax I had posted, just an error in the arrangement of the select statement. I am a little embarrassed to say I didn't originally use the `or die(mysql_error());`. But, I **usually** use the die function... really I do (hehe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The query will be required to run on every page the user loads and we
>   have over 30,000 permissions, and 3,000 roles. I am just trying **very
>   hard** to keep my number of queries to a minimum. We also host our 7
>   sites on a server in our office, and the server doesn't seem to be
>   capable of handling the amount of traffic we generate (unfortunately I
>   have no control over this)

I see that your intentions are good, but let me tell you this:

The "number of queries" is not the right way to measure your site's performance.

Many times 2 simple queries use less resources than 1 complex.

Also there are other ways to speed up your sites:

- Assess if you really need all those roles and permissions loaded on each request. Maybe querying for only the role/permission needed is enough.
- Have proper indexes
- Utilize caching techniques to reduce the load (site content)

So finally, I tried to come up with query to satisfy what was asked:

```
select * from (
    select ur.role_id, p.*
    from user_roles ur 
    left join permissions_role pr on ur.role_id =  pr.role_id
    left join permissions p on p.id = pr.perm_id
    where ur.user_id = '$userid'
  union all
    select null as role_id, p.*
    from permissions_user pu
    join permissions p on p.id = pu.perm_id
    where pu.user_id = '$userid'
) sub
group by ifnull(name,role_id) -- group by to eliminate duplicates
```

But this is not good on performance. 
You are much better off with 2 queries: 1st to get all permissions for user

```
select p.* from permissions p
join permissions_role pr on pr.perm_id = p.id
join user_roles ur on ur.role_id =  pr.role_id and ur.user_id = '$userid'
union
select p.* from permissions p
join  permissions_user pu on pu.perm_id = p.id and pu.user_id = '$userid';
```

and 2nd to get all roles.

Comment: Thank you for your help. FYI for others who view the question... I also posted an answer which reflects the final working queries and supporting code to demonstrate how the queries are used.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** Here are the final working queries. Also, I thought it might be useful for others to see how the queries are used, so a full explanation is included.

```
//build the array(s)
$userperms = array();
$userroles = array();
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])):
    //get the userid
    $thisuserid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    //get the permissions for each of the user's roles
    $Cpermissions_role = mysql_query(" 
    SELECT      r.type, ur.user_id, pr.perm_id, ur.role_id, p.name
    FROM        user_roles ur
    LEFT JOIN   permissions_role pr ON ur.role_id = pr.role_id
    LEFT JOIN   roles r ON ur.role_id = r.id
    LEFT JOIN   permissions p ON p.id = pr.perm_id
    WHERE       ur.user_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
    //get the extra permissions for the user
    $Cpermissions_user = mysql_query("
    SELECT      pu.user_id, pu.perm_id, p.name
    FROM        permissions_user pu
    LEFT JOIN   permissions p ON p.id = pu.perm_id
    WHERE       pu.user_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
    //build an array of the user's roles & an array of the user's permissions
    if(mysql_num_rows($Cpermissions_role) > 0):
        while($Rpermissions_role = mysql_fetch_array($Cpermissions_role)):
            if(empty($userperms)):
                $userperms[] = $Rpermissions_role['name'];
            elseif(!in_array($Rpermissions_role['name'],$userperms)):
                $userperms[] = $Rpermissions_role['name'];
            endif;
            if(empty($userroles)):
                $userroles[] = $Rpermissions_role['type'];
            elseif(!in_array($Rpermissions_role['type'],$userroles)):
                $userroles[] = $Rpermissions_role['type'];
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    if(mysql_num_rows($Cpermissions_user) > 0):
        while($Rpermissions_user = mysql_fetch_array($Cpermissions_user)):
            if(empty($userperms)):
                $userperms[] = $Rpermissions_user['name'];
            elseif(!in_array($Rpermissions_user['name'],$userperms)):
                $userperms[] = $Rpermissions_user['name'];
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
endif;
/**
 * Determines if the user has permission for the page or parts of page
 * @param string $perm the permission constant
 * @return boolean true if user has access, false if not
 */
function hasPermission($perm){
    global $userperms;
    if(empty($userperms)):
        return false;
    else:
        if(is_array($userperms)):
            if(in_array($perm,$userperms)):
                return true;
            else:
                return false;
            endif;
        else:
            if($perm == $userperms):
                return true;
            else:
                return false;
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

Then, I use the following decision statement:

```
if(hasPermission("ACCESS_HOME_PAGE")):
    //perform circus tricks here
endif;
```

So, now `print_r($userperms);` outputs this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => ACCESS_TELEPHONELIST_PAGE
    [1] => ACCESS_VACATIONSCHED_PAGE
    [2] => ACCESS_TOURSCHED_PAGE
    [3] => ACCESS_WORKSCHED_PAGE
    [4] => ACCESS_RESOURCES_LINKS
    [5] => ACCESS_PMTOOL_PAGE
    [6] => ACCESS_TOOLSTOOL_PAGE
    [7] => ACCESS_SHOPTOOLLIST_PAGE
    [8] => ACCESS_TOOLINVENTORY_PAGE
    [9] => ACCESS_MANAGETOOLLIST_PAGE
    [10] => ACCESS_TOOLREPORTS_PAGE
    [11] => ACCESS_JOBSLIST_LINKS
    [12] => MAIN_TAB_TOOLSTOOL
    [13] => ADMIN_TAB_PODMANAGEMENT
    [14] => TOOL_TAB_SHOPTOOLLIST
    [15] => ACCESS_HOME_PAGE
)
```

And, `print_r($userroles);` outputs this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => administrator
    [1] => humanresourcees
    [2] => podmanager
)
```

And, just to be thorough, here is the JavaScript I use to access the php array:

```
var js_userperms = new Array();
js_userperms = ["<?php echo join("\", \"", $userperms); ?>"];
```

And, the jQuery decision statement:

```
if(jQuery.inArray("ACCESS_HOME_PAGE", js_userperms) != -1){
    //perform circus tricks here
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because of the query was horribly wrong. You have deleted that for now.

Comment: I tried by answering the question. Since you accepted your own answer few hours later I didn't feel like contributing more time. Cheers.